# How to Validate Credit Card in Stripe before creating payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to create card elements on my app. When clicking Checkout, I create a payment intent and then create the user account and save the order in the database. Then I process the payment.

There are a lot of failed payment intents in my Stripe account. Is there a way to create payment intent only if the user has entered card details? Right now, it just creates the intent and order and user account, even if the user has not entered any card details at all or has entered an invalid card number. I want to create a user account and order only if at least the card details are entered and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Stripe guide for accepting a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) has you create a Payment Intent before collecting payment details (like card information) and is the recommended approach.  Incomplete Payment Intents don't hurt anything, and some people use them for metrics (like tracking conversion).

That said, you explicitly said there are *failed* Payment Intents on your account, so you might be trying to confirm them before the payment details have been entered.  I recommend reading through the guide linked above and following that approach, which will avoid issues with confirming before payment details have been collected.

Comment: My bad, it is not 'failed' payments, but incomplete ones. They are created when I hit the checkout button while testing without filling in the card details. I would at least want to give a user a message like "Credit card number can't be left blank".

Comment: As mentioned above the incomplete ones can be used for conversion metrics or simply ignored.  They represent people landing on your checkout page and then going away, not people trying to pay without entering a card number.  If you're using Stripe Elements they'll get friendly error messages in cases like that.

Comment: I guess you're right. I shouldn't worry about such records in my orders table or the stripe account.